# Find standard deviation in normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

X follows normal distribution X~(μ,σ) and P(x<20)=0.75 and P(x<10)=0.25. What is μ and σ? I know the mean is 15, however, I can't find the standard deviation. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $P(X<20)=P(Z<5/\sigma) =0.75$ and $P(X<10)=P(Z< -5/\sigma)=0.25$, look up a table and use symmetry and these to back out $\sigma$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
0.25 = {} & \Pr(Z<-0.675) \qquad (\text{from the table}) \\[8pt]
 = {} & \Pr(X<10) = \Pr(X-\mu<-5) \\[8pt]
= {} & \Pr\left( \frac{X-\mu} \sigma < \frac{-5}\sigma \right) \\[8pt]
= {} & \Pr\left( Z < \frac{-5}\sigma \right) \\[8pt]
\text{So } -0.675 = {} & \frac{-5}\sigma.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

For a standard normal $Z \sim N(0, 1)$, you can look up (from a table or a computer) what $z_{0.25}$ satisfies $P(Z < z_{0.25}) = 0.25$.
Then just note that $\frac{X - 15}{\sigma}$ is standard normal, so you can equate this to $z_{0.25}$ and solve for $\sigma$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It makes sense, but I looked up some tables and they don't show any z-scores for the exact probability of 0.25, do you know a site with a calculator or a table with the exact